# Create a file TXT file from an email pipe

Tags: php, email

I'm using "Pipe to program in your home directory" from hosting cpanel. I'm able to receive an email and parse it. I'm hoping to create a TXT file from a received email. This is what I have so far, and it isn't working:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

$fp = fopen('emailfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($email, TRUE));
fclose($fp);

?>
```

I'm able to open and parse the email, but no file is created.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: any error log entries to go off?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know where to find any errors as there is no "screen" to view. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the directory in which where you are writing this.

Use an absolute path to write the file as well as errors if you can.

Comment: This is the path of my script: /public_html/email/parse.php. This is how I list my path:     $fp = fopen('/public_html/email/emailfile.txt', 'w'); How would I use an absolute path in this case? I apologize If that is a dumb question.

Comment: Usually the home directory is at /home/username. See the current directory where the script is present with `pwd` through the console. Usually /tmp/ is a directory that exists in linux based on environments where you can read/write data to/from.

so the full path would be /home/username/public_html/email/emailfile.txt . Otherwise you may not be able to see your file which is written.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I updated the path to the absolute path as you suggest and problem solved.